# Troubleshooting "bursty" network traffic

Tags: wireless-networking, latency, packet-loss

I've been having a problem with my Internet connection ever since moving to San Francisco, and it's driving me absolutely up the wall. After using my network connection for anywhere between five and thirty minutes, suddenly packets will start backing up at my router before being delivered in short bursts. For instance, [ping will show several dropped packets in a row](https://gist.github.com/stouset/5317162) before all of the backed-up responses are delivered at the same instant.

I'm using a cable modem provided by Comcast, hooked up via Ethernet to a Time Capsule, to which I am connecting a pair of MacBook Pros and an Apple TV.

The cable modem has been replaced. The Time Capsule has been replaced. I have physically moved apartments, so it's not the wiring. My wife and I both experience this behavior simultaneously on our separate laptops (and the Apple TV has its connection interrupted at the same time too). It is briefly resolved (for a few minutes) by:

- removing and reinserting the Ethernet cable connecting the two
- switching to the "guest" WiFi network, or from the guest network back to the primary one

It is resolved for up to thirty minutes by:

- power cycling the Time Capsule
- power cycling the cable modem

When this happens, I can ping the Time Capsule itself with no packet loss or latency. The problem does occur when trying to ping the next hop, however.

What on Earth can this possibly be? I have, as far as I can tell, ruled out all possible hardware issues. I haven't found anyone else with this issue through extensive Googling either.

Comment: A few hints that may provide direction: try `ifconfig -a` & look at ethernet errors. If they exist, your laptop network hardware or the first hop hardware port (time capsule) may be faulty.  Also try `netstat -s` to look for errors at a higher layer (TCP/IP) if ethernet (layer 2) is fine and TCP isn't it may indicate a TCP configuration issue (e.g. outgoing buffers too small). Lastly, look at the MTU setup on your time capsule.  It may be too large so fragmentation occurs. If it is set to 1500 bytes, try something like 1472. Adding these outputs to the Q may help too.

Comment: Unfortunately, OSX doesn't seem to have an equivalent for `ifconfig -a`. But this issue is happening on multiple client devices (which don't have the problem elsewhere), and has persisted through a replacement of the Time Capsule hardware. `netstat -s` doesn't show any red flags: a handful of bad packets out of tens of millions. And the MTU on the Time Capsule is not configurable. `ping -c 1 -D -s 1472 example.com` works (and is the maximum size before ping fails), indicating an MTU of 1500.

Comment: Sounds like you found the culprit (too big MTU).  The question is how to force it to 1472.

Comment: Is there a further test I could do to confirm? I'm not convinced it's MTU. It doesn't really seem to exhibit the typical symptoms, from my experience.

Comment: perhaps you may try: `sudo ifconfig mtu 1472 en1` (YMMV) and run like this for a while to see if it alleviates the problem?  Sorry, not using Mac OS-X so not sure if the `ifconfig` parameters and the name of your ethernet interface are right for your env.  If it helps, I could write a real answer.

Comment: Not being familiar with the Timecapsule product, is it behaving as a WiFi base station, and NAT/router for your home network?

Could you describe the Ethernet cable connecting the Timecapsule to the cable modem?  (length, age, condition, pre-made/home-made/custom-made)

Comment: Yes to the first part. The Ethernet cable has been replaced recently. It was several years old, probably 4ft long, in perfect condition (twist-ties never even removed). It was replaced with a similar cable.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, `/sbin/ifconfig` has been included in every version of OS X from its beta version, onward...  It was a requirement of mine before I bought my first Mac.  However, `ifconfig -a` does not report errors.

An echo-request packet with the [DF] bit set, and a size of 1472 appears to pad out to 1500 bytes:

```
mini-nevie:~ root# ping -D -s 1472 -c 1 192.168.2.1
PING 192.168.2.1 (192.168.2.1): 1472 data bytes
1480 bytes from 192.168.2.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=1.130 ms

mini-nevie:~ root# tcpdump -i en0 -nevvK icmp
tcpdump: listening on en0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
00:34:46.177055 3c:07:54:5c:ab:ad > 00:13:a3:71:17:25, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1514: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 46904, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 1500)
    192.168.2.11 > 192.168.2.1: ICMP echo request, id 56908, seq 0, length 1480
00:34:46.178084 00:13:a3:71:17:25 > 3c:07:54:5c:ab:ad, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 1514: (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 48096, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 1500)
    192.168.2.1 > 192.168.2.11: ICMP echo reply, id 56908, seq 0, length 1480
```

An additional point of reference can be had by using `snmpwalk` with `-c public -v1` and your cable modem's management address, which I think is 192.168.100.1.  A perusal of the output will allow you to determine specific interface's statistics.  As well, depending on the cable modem make and model, connecting to `http://192.168.100.1` or `http://192.168.100.1:8080`  can give a wealth of information from the device's built-in webserver.

And... `netstat -s` gives protocol statistics.  `netstat -i` will give hardware statistics, which might point to a problem.